# Chart.js change color of the radio chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

please look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rt2.png), I'm using react-chartjs v5 and I don't find anything in the documentation that helps me remove the red numbers in the image or change the color of the chart and change the color of the labels, it's days that I'm stuck on this please help me get unstuck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example